# ScrollTop() Doesn't work, Not sure what's going on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

So below I have some of my JQuery code that should be causing the clicked value to scroll down to another section of the page.  I'm not sure what's wrong with my code as it has stopped working, so I'd appreciate any feedback I can get on this.

```
$(".list-item1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".image1").offset().top
    }, 700);
});

$("#list-item2").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".image2").offset().top
    }, 700);
});

$("#list-item3").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".image3").offset().top
    }, 700);
});
```

Comment: Code looks fine, something else is causing it. Does event even fire when you click the divs? Do alerts there and check that first.

Comment: share full code for other error in your code

Comment: No, don't share the "full code".  [mcve], emphasis on the "Verifiable" part.  (But first look at your error console; usually when a function "stops working" it's because you have introduced a syntax error somewhere in there.)

Comment: Show your html that's related to these js please. I will take a wild guess that `$(".list-item1")` probably should be `$("#list-item1")` or the other 2 should be using a dot and not hash